# Push Notification Certificate

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, apple-push-notifications

I have enable push and then created the distribution profile but not created push certificate, now i want to add push service in my app how can i do ??
if i create push certificate after uploading app on app store will this effect my live app.

i have followed following steps:

1. created distribution profile with push service enable.
2. i have not created push certificate and i have downloaded distribution certificate with       push service enable flag.
3. uploaded app on app store (with push enable flag).
4. i have created pem file by my distribution profile (that is wrong one)

now my push notification is not working , i want to enable push services in my live app.

can i follow following steps for that :

1. create new APNS certificate for push service.
2. can we use this without resubmitting app to AppStore.

Or do i need to create new provisioning profile & resubmit app to appstore?

Help us....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, You need to add a APNS distribution certificate for the App you created in your Developer account. Create push notification certificate (prod.pem) and pass to your backened.
It will work, no need to submit again.

Follow this [link](https://blog.serverdensity.com/how-to-build-an-apple-push-notification-provider-server-tutorial/) to create pem certificate.